# How to edit the right click menu in Gnome

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

[image]Is there a simple way to edit the right click menu in Gnome?

I am running 14.04 Ubuntu Gnome, and for some reason the right click menu "whites out" my selection instead of highlighting it.

I was unable to take a screenshot of the menu up.

EDIT: Screenshot up

Comment: Are you saying, that the foreground and background colours of highlighted context menu entries make the entry text illegible?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. When I mouse-over my selection it becomes completely blanked out, instead of highlighted.

Comment: By the way you can take screen shots of context menus with `gnome-screenshot -i` and setting a delay in the menu before capturing the screen. It'll save the screen shot to your pictures folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the colour scheme of your desktop environment is “off”.

### (Re-)setting the GTK colour scheme

- One possible cause is that `gnome-settings-manager` misbehaves or crashed. That can often be fixed by logging out of your account and logging in again.
- Another possibility is that the colour settings themselves are somehow corrupted and you need to reset them through the system settings manager display options. Maybe try other colour schemes for comparison. You may need to log out and back in for it to take effect.
- Similar to the previous solution, you can try select other colour schemes with `gnome-tweak-tool`, if that's still around in 14.04.

### Fixing a broken GTK theme

The default theme for the Gnome Shell in Ubuntu 14.04 is Adwaita. You can reinstall ist with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-themes-standard\*
```

Reload the current theme with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, enter `r` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Comment: logging out and back in has not fixed anything. Cannot find a color settings to test that. added screenshot to original post

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a 14.04 setup to poke around myself. Maybe the third suggestion in my recent edit helps.

Comment: added screenshot, cursor is over "Save As" and it's clearly missing. Will try tweak. EDIT Tweak worked when changing GTK to High Contrast, but personally I think it's an ugly look. Anything I can do other than leaving it on High Contrast?

Comment: At least now we know that I identified the problem cause correctly. I'll update my answer.

Comment: broken GTK theme is Adwaita. So I should `sudo apt-get install --reinstall adwaita`?

Comment: Please see the update to my answer.